# Insert array into MySQL database from form

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, insert

I have tried inserting array data from form into my database but am getting only the last row:

I want to insert these array into Database:

```
ProductID Quantity
2            10
3            5
4            8
```

but I am seeing only this data in my Database:

```
ProductID Quantity
4            8
```

See my code below:

```
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASS' ,'');
define('DB_NAME','store');
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$productID=$_POST['product_id'];
$IssueQty=$_POST['quantity'];

$inventory=mysqli_query($con,"insert into inventory_log(productID, IssueQty)
values('$productID', '$IssueQty')");
```

Comment: You are inserting only one set of row then how you can expect the DB to show 3 rows?

Comment: can you insert a single row? if so, can you run exactly the same code in a loop?

Comment: use foreach , foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 2):

An example of multiple INSERT:

```
$statement = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO inventory_log (productID, IssueQty)
VALUES (?,?)");
foreach ($_POST as $row) {
    $statement->bind_param($row['product_id'],$row['quantity']);
    $statement->execute();
}
```

Comment: thanks mPareek for your help. just wondering how to replace this: (?,?)

Comment: What do you mean replace `(?,?)`? These are placeholders and that is how the SQL should look like. You must bind the parameters inside the loop

Comment: You don't need to replace it. They will be automatically replaced by `bind_param()`. This is known as prepared statement and is a more secure way to write queries. See this [mysqli_prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)